# Select on non-blocking FileDescriptors

Tags: java, android, io, nio

I have one or more non-blocking `FileDescriptor` objects (already created and passed to me from some subsystem). I want to wait and then read from them using some kind of select(). How do I do this in Java (Android)? Can I use the `Selector` class?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?  Same problem here (VpnService).

Comment: @CamHart Starting API level 21, the Android VpnService.Builder has an option to set the fd in blocking mode. Check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html#setBlocking(boolean)

Answer (score 2):

Reading the comments from the other answer that was provided, I see that you are trying to make the VpnService fd blocking, something not supported in the lower android versions.

What I did was make the fd blocking through JNI code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we're not going to be able to use `Selector`s.

Let's try a different approach then.

Let's assume you have a method `open()` that returns the `FileDescriptor` that you want, but blocks on some IO operation. You want to be able to continue about your business while the `FileDescriptor`s are being fetched without waiting for this operation, and you want to know when they're ready.

Try something like this:

```
// IMPORTS
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

class FileDescriptorFetcher extends Thread {
  final BlockingQueue<FileDescriptor> queue =
      new LinkedBlockingQueue<FileDescriptor>();
  // let's just pretend Openable provides FileDescriptors from open()
  final Openable[] from;
  boolean done;

  FileDescriptorFetcher(Openable[] fromThese) {
    from = fromThese;
    done = false;
    start();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (Openable o : from)
      queue.offer(o.open());

    done = true;
  }

  public boolean isDone() {
    return done;
  }

  public boolean descriptorAvailable() {
    return !queue.isEmpty();
  }

  /* blocks if there are more descriptors to get and none are available,
   * returns null if all have been fetched already */
  public FileDescriptor fetchDescriptor() {
    return done
        ? null
        : queue.take();
  }
}
```

With this class you would just pass it an array of `FileDescriptor` creators in its constructor and it would start opening them. To get all the `FileDescriptor`s that have been produced so far:

```
FileDescriptorFetcher fetcher;

// init fetcher

while (fetcher.descriptorAvailable()) {
  doStuff(fetcher.fetchDescriptor());
}
```

To get every single `FileDescriptor` as soon as possible:

```
while (!fetcher.isDone()) {
  doStuff(fetcher.fetchDescriptor());
}
```

Comment: That is the problem there is no way to get SelectableChannel from FileDescriptor. Simply google this issue... I am asking how to implement it overcoming this problem

Comment: Well then, here's a philosophical question. Why do you need to wait select? What are they actually blocking on? From what I can discern, you don't want to block on the actual `FileDescriptor`, which only refers to the actual _result_ of the already-completed operation of opening the file. As you say, there don't seem to be any `SelectableChannel`s for files in `java.nio`; you are probably looking to do is create a new `Thread` object that opens up the file streams and provides the resulting `FileDescriptors` in a synchronized context from an internal list as the job gets done.

Comment: The file descriptor I have actually not File System FD. I got it from VpnService (see  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145615/how-to-read-from-non-blocking-java-io-filedescriptor)). So need to read it with select()

Comment: I replaced my answer with something that handles the problem more generically. How does that look?

Comment: If this still isn't it, and you are wanting to read from the streams they indicate with some process you haven't described at all, your best bet would be to simply implement a `SelectableChannel` wrapper for the `FileDescriptor` objects you get and use that with a regular `Selector`.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. But the problem still persist - doStuff() is the problematic place here, it should do the work in polling mode that is not good from the performance point of view. We have implemented the solving converting this FD to be blocking and using Pipe.SourceChannel together with Selectors

Comment: Yeah, `Selector`s can only really be used with things that are actually going to perform a blocking operation. It sounds like your main issue was finding that.